# Gmail Access Filter for GCP VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

How to setup access to VM instance with static ip through Google OAuth like Cloudflare Access?

Now I can setup access only for Service Account, Tags and some range of IP Addresses
How it can be configured only for specific gmail-users?

Screenshot of Cloudflare Access when I'm trying to connect to VM with static IP address:

[image]

Comment: You can configure IAM Official Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview [![Example of IAM architecture by Google IAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we07M.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we07M.png)

Comment: You want to grant access to your VMs (ssh) via Google Sign In and only allow access via specific static IP?

Comment: @JanHernandez I want to serve a web app with SSR on Compute Engine with Google Identity.

Comment: As I understood, GCP not provides free permanent dns name, and if you want configure some Google Identity you must have own domain.

https://serverfault.com/questions/948800/setting-up-publicly-accessible-dns-name-in-google-cloud-dns

Comment: you can use [GCP IAP proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto) to enable this feature, but as you mention it is necessary a domain to setup the OAuth consent scree

Answer (score 0):

Jan Hernandez already answered in a comment, however I still want to answer:

[Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto) actually lets you perform what you are looking for, it's a GCP component that give you the option to restrict access to resources by access level, this can be done with gmail users as well, however you'll need to set up an OAuth consent screen.

Give it a look and try it.